# Where does IntelliJ IDEA keep run/debug configurations?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, run-configuration

Intellij IDEA will automatically create a run/debug configuration when you run any item that doesn't have a permanent run/debug configuration already present.

You can then save the run/debug configuration that was generated to make it permanent.

When you save a configuration, where is it saved?

Comment: As near as I can tell, they're saved in `<project_directory>/.idea/workspace.xml`.

Comment: And if you mark a configuration as shared, it will be stored in a sub-folder under `.idea`. That you can use to copy the configuration to another project.

Comment: @yegodm Thanks - I finally put 2-and-2 together and realized that your comment explains how to make the configurations separate from the `workspace.xml` file (per Slaw's comment and Sand's answer) so that it will be saved by git into a repo (that file is excluded by the `.gitignore` files I found for good reason). That's the real problem I was trying to solve!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

run/debug configurations for a project are stored in the .idea/workspace.xml file inside the project location. You can see those entries under the `<component name="RunManager"` node if you search for "RunManager" in that file.

[image]

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: And in my project it seems to be the only file that has no Local History... All my Run/Debug configurations are gone and I have no way of restoring them.